# VOIP service with an API that can be resold?

Tags: c#, api, sdk, voip

Looking to add dialing capabilities to my desktop application. Requires:

1. API/SDK to allow seamless integration into C#. An application user would have no idea who the VOIP provider is.
2. Allows re-sale in license. We include it as part of the package and charge our end users

Any packages out there that fit this bill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [Ozeki VoIP SDK](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com). It is based on C#.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to wrap up full softphone capabilities the main ones I'm aware are [NCH's Express Talk](http://www.nch.com.au/talk/sdk.html) and [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/). I've never attempted to integrate with either so don't know how easy or hard it will be with C#. If you only need your application to be able to intiate and/or control calls you could use any SIP stack, an open source C# one being [sipsorcery](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

2600hz does this (and it's open-source).

Git repo here: https://github.com/2600hz/kazoo

Main site here: http://2600hz.com

I think this is what you're looking for although we don't have a softphone built-in (but integrate with most existing softphone clients).

Cheers,
Joshua

Disclaimer: I'm the community manager for 2600hz.